# Uncaught Error: Could not find module ember-cli-tooltipster/components/tool-tipster

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I just installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-tooltipster on my ember cli app.

```
$ npm install ember-cli-tooltipster --save-dev

$ ember g ember-cli-tooltipster
```

however when I load the rmber app on the browser i get the following error from loader.js

> loader.js:58 Uncaught Error: Could not find module
>   ember-cli-tooltipster/components/tool-tipster

Any idea on why I am getting this error ?

```
$ ember version --verbose
version: 0.2.2
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://www.ember-cli.com/#watchman for more info.
http_parser: 2.3
node: 0.12.2
v8: 3.28.73
uv: 1.4.2-node1
zlib: 1.2.8
modules: 14
openssl: 1.0.1m
npm: 2.7.4
```

package.json::

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.12",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.0",
    "broccoli-merge-trees": "^0.2.1",
    "broccoli-static-compiler": "^0.2.1",
    "ember-cli": "^0.2.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.3.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "0.0.7",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^0.6.0",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-less": "^1.1.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth": "^0.7.2",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-oauth2": "^0.7.2",
    "ember-cli-tooltipster": "0.0.6",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.12",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-mousetrap": "0.2.0",
    "express": "^4.8.5",
    "glob": "^4.4.0"
  }
```

** I have restarted ember server after install. and completely reinstalled both node and  bower modules.

** Also to determine why its not producing an error on `ember build` command. I created a custom component to extend this component using: `import TooltipsterComponent from 'ember-cli-tooltipster/components/tool-tipster';`
 and then ran `ember build` and it build successfully. However when I`ember serve` then load the app from the browser I get the error message in the javascript console.

Comment: Just tried it in my existing ember-cli app and it did work. Did you get a `tooltipster": "~3.3.0"` entry or similar in your bower.json? Maybe you can share an example of your setup?

Comment: Have you tried using 'ember install:addon ember-cli-tooltipster'? Rather than npm install.. It runs the addons blueprint for you and maybe it doesn't something else that you're not behind the scenes to get it working